# Конструкция с "или" перед тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, или

Смотрите. Конструкция:

> Бегемот, или гиппопотам, – не что иное, как животное.

Здесь "или" обозначает не дизъюнкцию, а пояснение (бегемот – это гиппопотам). По идее должно обособляться с двух сторон. Тире в этом случае поглощает запятую или нет? Нужна ли она после "гиппопотам"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие обороты с союзом *или* обособляются с двух сторон. Примеры Розенталя:
*Отметим два вида возбуждающей, или входной, функции.

Кольчатый тюлень, или нерпа, относится к числу ластоногих.

Флексия, или окончание, имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи.*

На общих основаниях, так как имеется обособленный оборот, запятая нужна:
*Бегемот, или гиппопотам, – (это) не что иное, как животное.*

В таких случаях запятая обозначает, к чему относится часть после тире. Запятая не ставится, если фрагмент после тире относится только к обороту.